# mod_rewrite request for file to domain root and append query parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

OK this is working on my domain (http://staging.whiterabbitexpress.com)

```
RewriteRule ^send-your-request/?$ http://staging.whiterabbitexpress.com [NC,QSA,L]
```

but is there a way to redirect to the root without typing the whole domain name?

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^send-your-request/?$ / [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^send-your-request/?$ index.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^send-your-request/?$ /index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

nada, nada, nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `R` flag in the square brackets, which tell the rewrite engine to redirect instead of internally rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^send-your-request/?$ / [NC,QSA,L,R]
```

You can also say `R=301` if you want a permanent redirect. The reason why you didn't need it before is because when you include the `http://domain.name` in your rewrite target, it implicitly redirects with a 302.